# Вопрос по расширению для Chrome

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Написал расширение для Chrome под Яндекс Дзен. Все работает, НО только если нажать F5. При переходе по внутренним ссылкам код не подхватывается. Подскажите в какую сторону думать?

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "ZStat",
    "description": "Расширенная статистика для Дзен",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icons": {"1": "icon.png"},
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

       "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "js/stat.js","js/core.js","js/charts.js","js/animated.js" ],
      "matches": [ "https://zen.yandex.ru/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
   } ],
      
    "web_accessible_resources": ["css/modal.css"    ],
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [ "storage", "https://zen.yandex.ru/" ]
}
```

Притом в stat.js ради теста я просто поставил console.log(1); — выводится 1 раз и все. Без обновления страницы код не подхватывается если переходить по урлам... Что то забыл, не учел. Сам на php 15 лет писал.
Подозреваю что внутри редактора Дзена идет перехват клика и ссылка рисуется динамически. Как такое отследить ?
Спасибо